# Multivariate Gaussian Copulas to model dependent random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

Assume that the probability distributions of several random variables and their correlation matrix are known, say

$x_1\sim\text{lognormal}(1,1)$,

$x_2\sim \text{uniform}(1,2)$,

$x_3\sim\text{Beta}(1,1)$,

and correlation matrix

$\Sigma {\rm{ = }}\left[ \begin{array}{l}
1.0,0.4,0.8\\
0.4,1.0,0.7\\
0.8,0.7,1.0
\end{array} \right]$.

How to use multivariate Gaussian Copulas to model these dependent random variables?

---

**Update:**

I tried the following code based on the links provided in @F.Amer answer:

```
Correlation <- matrix(c(1,0.4,0.8,0.4,1,0.7,0.8,0.7,1),3,3) # correlation matrix of lognormal, weibull, and beta distributions
NormCop <- normalCopula(param, dim = 3, dispstr = "un")

MyMvd <- mvdc(NormCop, c("lnorm", "weibull","beta"),list(list(meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1), list(shape=1, scale = 1), list(shape1=1, shape2=1)))`
```

How to set the parameter `param` in `normalCopula` function?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @RubenvanBergen, I just give a small example.  It is a general question regarding use of Gaussian Copulas for modeling dependent random variables.

Answer (score 2):

To model a multivariate data using copula models you need to follow two steps:

1. You have to decide which model you need to use to estimate the copula parameters. For example, there are full parametric models (Maximum likelihood estimate), two-step estimation model (Inference of Margin model), and non-parametric model.  The first two models may provide poor estimated in the case of unknown margins. Since, from your question, that you know the margins, so it is good to go with one of the first two methods.
2. Fit copula function and estimate its parameters.

Copula package is a nice R package that can help you to fit and estimate the model parameters.

For a very good example, please see, https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v021i04/v21i04.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, the marginal distribution of each random variable is konwn as well as random variables' correlation matrix. It will be greatly appreciated if you can give a small examples of using Copula package for implementation.

Comment: Of course. Just give me a short time.

Comment: Please see the edit. There are a very good explanations in the providing paper.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I failed to find where to enter the correlation (covariance) matrix of marginal distributons. My code lines are: Correlation<-matrix(c(1,0.4,0.8,0.4,1,0.7,0.8,0.7,1),3,3) # correlation matrix of lognormal, weibull, and beta distributions
NormCop <- normalCopula(param, dim = 3, dispstr = "un")
MyMvd <- mvdc(NormCop, c("lnorm", "weibull","beta"),list(list(meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1), list(shape=1, scale = 1), list(shape1=1, shape2=1)))
How to set the parameter "param" in normalCopula function?

Comment: could you please pass your code in your question?

Comment: Why do you need to pass the correlation matrix? What do you need copula to find for you?

Comment: You can set `param` as a vector. `param=c()`.

Comment: NormCop <- normalCopula(param=c(0.4,0.8,0.7), dim = 3, dispstr = "un")\\


MyMvd <- mvdc(NormCop, c("lnorm", "weibull","beta"),list(list(meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1), list(shape=1, scale = 1), list(shape1=1, shape2=1)))


RealDistributions <- rMvdc(1e5, MyMvd)


CorCopula<-cor(RealDistributions)\\

But CorCopula is not equal to Correlation matrix.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: You use a simulation data, then you should repeat your data, say 100 times` and then take the mean. Also, use `fit` function in copula package to give you the estimation of the dependences parameters of your variables.

Comment: I wanna transform the known marginals with dependence structure specified by correlation matrix to the multivariate Gaussian distribution. In essence, the task is to estimate the correlation matrix of  the transformed multivariate Gaussian distribution. Then use transformed multivariate Gaussian distribution to sample the dependent marginals.  In this case, the correlation matrix of the samples should be equal to (or close to) the defined correlation matrix.

Comment: You need to estimate the margins and then transform them to copula data.